# How can I insert content at the beginning of my EditorState in Draft.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

So I'm trying to write a method to insert a given string to the beginning of the EditorState.
Basically the string should always be at the beginning, the font style should be italic, there should be a line break after the new content and the cursor should be directly after the new content.
So the content would be:
"New content[cursor position]

old already exisiting content"

At the moment my function looks like this:

```
insertContent = (content: any) => {
  const currentContent = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent();
  const currentSelection = this.state.editorState.getSelection();

  const newContent = Modifier.replaceText(
    currentContent,
    currentSelection,
    content
  );

  const newEditorState = EditorState.push(this.state.editorState, newContent, 'insert-characters');

  this.setState({
    editorState: EditorState.moveFocusToEnd(RichUtils.insertSoftNewline(newEditorState))
  });
}
```

It already adds the given content and a line break but the new content is always after the old content and the new content has no italic font-style.

Comment: I struggled a lot with using draft-js , i suggest you to go with ReactQuill instead and try this. many features are not available in draft-js , you either have to custom write those or use other lib , but with react-quill my major problems are resolved easily.

Comment: Have you tried using `Modifier.insertText` instead of `Modifier.replaceText`?

Answer (score 1):

**To answer your questions:**

> Basically the string should always be at the beginning

You can use `Modifier.insertText` to insert the new content at the beginning.

> the font style should be italic

For this to happen you need to merge your font style with the `italic` style:

```
const italicStyle = this.state.editorState.getCurrentInlineStyle().merge(
  Immutable.Map({fontStyle: 'italic'})
);
```

> there should be a line break after the new content

You can achieve this by using a `\n` line break:

```
`${content}\n`
```

> the cursor should be directly after the new content

You can use `EditorState.forceSelection` to move the cursor to a new position.

Given your initial code example used a type annotation (`content: any`), I am providing a **full example using TypeScript**:

```
import React from 'react';
import {EditorState, Modifier, SelectionState} from 'draft-js';

interface Props {
}

interface State {
  editorState: EditorState;
}

class YourReactComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  insertContent = (content: string) => {
    const currentContent = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const currentSelection = this.state.editorState.getSelection();

    const italicStyle = this.state.editorState.getCurrentInlineStyle().merge(
      Immutable.Map({fontStyle: 'italic'})
    );

    const newContent = Modifier.insertText(
      currentContent,
      currentSelection,
      `${content}\n`,
      italicStyle
    );

    const newEditorState = EditorState.push(
      this.state.editorState,
      newContent,
      'insert-characters'
    );

    const newSelection = new SelectionState({
      anchorKey: newContent.getFirstBlock().getKey(),
      anchorOffset: 0,
      focusKey: newContent.getFirstBlock().getKey(),
      focusOffset: content.length
    });

    this.setState({
      editorState: EditorState.forceSelection(newEditorState, newSelection)
    });
  };
}
```

Don't forget to install `@types/draft-js` when using it. Hope it helps!